# Choose your own adventure - choice function?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm working on a choose-your-own-adventure game in Python to try to learn how to code. I might be doing this entirely wrong, but I thought rather than just nesting if-elif-else statements endlessly, I could write some sort of function that would be a template for all choices in the game.

My ideas was to have every decision in a given scene to generate two lists - choices and outcomes. The "multitemplate" function would then load the choose and outcomes lists, present the options to the player, take in the answer, and call the correct function for the outcome given.

My issue is that the outcome list is a list of functions, which Python doesn't seem to like. It says I've not defined the functions properly, but when I define my outcome functions before calling "multitemplate", it just prints them first.

Here's my code:

```
#Function to allow the adventurer to make choices

def refusal():
    print("You stop at the roadsign you passed on your way into town. There are only two directions - towards Tarroway, or towards Angion, the town from whence you came.")

def guards():
    print("The guards stop you.")

def theinn():
    print("You follow the joyful chatter down the deserted street. Its source is a squat, one story building. A sign above the door reads \"The Forked Tongue\"")

choose = ["I walk towards the merry sounds.", "I turn on my heels and head back where I came from.","I stay where I am and watch the night quietly."]
outcome = [theinn(), refusal(), guards()]

def multitemplate(choose,outcome):
    global mychoice
    global carryon
    for x in range(len(choose)):
        print (f"{x+1}) " + choose[x], end="\n")
    mychoice = (input())-1
    while True:
        if (mychoice) in range(len(choose)):
            carryon = True
            outcome[mychoice]
            carrion()
        else:
            print("Please enter the number of the choice you wish to make.")
            carryon = False
            mychoice = int((input()))-1
```

I'd appreciate any input on how this should work properly, or if I'm going down a completely blind alley here.

Thanks!

Comment: `outcome` is **not** a list of functions. It is a list of the result of calling the functions. A list of functions would look like `outcome = [theinn, refusal, guards]` which you could call with something like  `outcome[1]()`

Comment: @Mark is absolutely correct. I noticed a couple other things with your program that you may want to take a look at though. Firstly, make sure you're using `int(input())-1` instead of just `input()-1`. I see you did it the second time, but not the first. Also, in your `while True:` loop, I don't see any condition that would end the loop (and allow the function to end). As it stands, your program would just print the result of your choice forever, I think.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you! That got the first choice selection working perfectly.